# Язык в исторической перспективе деградирует или развивается?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Встретились 2 противоположных мнения о происхождении языка.

**Первое мнение.** Лингвист Светлана Бурлак, ссылаясь на наблюдения за приматами, утверждает, что людям изначально не требовалось иметь развитый язык. Несколько слов: «палка», «еда», «тревога» — и хватит. Толчок к развитию языка дала, по её мнению, именно культура, а далее всё движется по сценарию обогащения и усложнения.

**Второе мнение.** Религовед Андрей Зубов, опираясь на данные археологических исследований, утверждает, что письменная история человечества демонстрирует не усложнение, а исключительно упрощение или, смелее, деградацию языка. Древнейшие известные языки, санскрит и древнекитайский, в разы сложнее тех, что используются сегодня. В качестве яркого и доступного примера пути языка от сложного к простому можно рассмотреть древнерусский и современный русский язык. Двойственное число, звательный падеж, более богатый алфавит, имперфект, плюсквамперфект — всё это ушло в прошлое, упростилось. На смену сложности приходят новые упрощения, типа Е вместо Ё, сокращения и т.д. А вот признаков усложнения языка не заметно. Максимум — заимствования, вытесняющие из словаря архаизмы. Но никак не прослеживается путь от простого к сложному. Достаточно сравнить многоярусный слог XVIII века с современным «телеграфным» стилем, чтобы это стало очевидно.

Уместно будет сослаться на наблюдение антропологов за современными дикими племенами, оторванными от цивилизации и не имеющими богатого культурного багажа. Вопреки стереотипам, они не общаются словарём Эллочки Людоедки, а проводят часы, тараторя у костра. Ещё бы, ведь разговоры — одно из немногих доступных им развлечений, а значит, ожидать «простого» языка от примитивного народа не следует. Простота, в этом свете, характерна для человека, имеющего достаточно соблазнительных альтернатив простой беседе и оттого не натренированного сложно выражать мысли.

Если опираться на такие рассуждения, выглядит так, будто язык во всей своей возник сразу сложным — таким, каким запечатлён в ранних китайских и индийских письменных памятниках.

**Вопрос.** Какой же путь проделывает язык? От сложного к простому? Он действительно всегда в охваченной письмом традиции деградировал, ища упрощённые формы? Или же есть факты, демонстрирующие обратное, — то, что примитивная грамматика каких-либо народов, сводящаяся к формам «подлежащее + сказуемое», обросла со временем 20 падежами, герундиями, склонениями, тропами и т.д.?

Comment: Я не могу сейчас найти ни ссылку, ни каких-либо других источников, но помню, что читал подобную дискуссию на Linguistics.SE (по-английски). Запомнилось, что многие специалисты (лингвисты) склоняются к тому, что процесс (условного †) упрощения/усложнения языка происходит циклически. "Беда" в том, что период этого цикла может составлять тысячелетия, поэтому современная наука просто не имеет достаточного фактического материала, чтобы этот процесс проследить.  († - "условного", поскольку что именно понимать под упрощением/усложнением - четких критериев тоже нет).

Comment: Как пример, в той же дискуссии упоминался китайский язык, который "упростился" в сравнении с известным нам древнекитайским практически до минимума, и в настоящий момент начал процесс усложнения. Детали, опять же, не вспомню - кажется, сейчас наблюдается появление/закрепление в языке неких суффиксов/окончаний, чего не было ещё несколько десятков лет назад...

Comment: (немного подумав) нет, увы, даже не уверен было ли это на Linguistics.SE и было ли это по-английски))

Comment: @tum_ большое спасибо за интересный взгляд на тему и за внимание к вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Весь вопрос в том, какие критерии выбраны для оценки степени развития или деградации языка. И ничего удивительного, что критерии, на которые опирается лингвист С.Бурлак, отличаются от критериев, выбранных религиоведом А.Зубовым.

**Что важно для лингвиста С.Бурлак?** Чтобы любую мысль, сколь бы сложной она ни была, можно было выразить максимально простым и доступным для понимания способом. А необходимость выражать самые простые мысли сложно и двусмысленно — это недостаток любых коммуникативных средств. По этим критериям языки развиваются.

**Что важно с точки зрения религиоведа А.Зубова**, если судить по приведённому в вопросе пересказу его позиции? Чтобы самая простая мысль выражалась так, чтобы одному Богу могло быть понятно, о чём пытались сказать. Идеал религии — священный текст, для понимания любого предложения из которого недостаточны были бы усилия лучших умов человечества на протяжении многих тысяч лет. В качестве примера идеального языка можно привести первую строку Евангелия от Иоанна, которую нельзя перевести на современные языки из-за их "деградации":

«В начале было Слово». С первых строк
Загадка. Так ли понял я намек?
Ведь я так высоко не ставлю слова,
Чтоб думать, что оно всему основа.
«В начале мысль была». Вот перевод.
Он ближе этот стих передает.
Подумаю, однако, чтобы сразу
Не погубить работы первой фразой.
Могла ли мысль в созданье жизнь вдохнуть?
«Была в начале сила». Вот в чем суть.
Но после небольшого колебанья
Я отклоняю это толкованье.
Я был опять, как вижу, с толку сбит:
«В начале было дело», – стих гласит.

Comment: Какой хороший стих! Один гений писал, другой переводил.

Comment: @grizzly большое спасибо за ответ. Думаю, будет справедливо, если я дополню здесь тем, что важно для религоведа А. Зубова, с его же слов. В вопросе я опустил этот момент, и, видимо, зря. Его центральная мысль заключается в том, что Бог дал язык человеку сразу во всей полноте. То есть наличие в письменных источниках сразу сложного языка доказывает его изначальность и высшее, духовное происхождение. Я просто счёл лишней эту информацию на форуме русского языка, но раз Вы коснулись того, что именно пытаются доказать учёные, счёл важным это уточнить.

Comment: @Третий глаз  Возможно, на Земле существовало несколько цивилизаций, и нельзя исключить, что духовные тексты достались китайцам от них. Но всё дело в том,  что развитому языку нужно развитое мышление, а вот его к языку, видимо,  не приложили. Поэтому и пришлось упрощать сложный язык, если в нем оказалось много лишнего. Есть аналогичное мнение, что и тело человека, как и его мозг используются не в полную силу, что тоже может доказывать определенную точку зрения (понятно, какую).

Comment: @Sharon Возможно и так. Я понимаю Вашу мысль, но, как Вы, я уверен, знаете, цивилизации древнее древнекитайской, месопотамской, древнеегипетской и праиндийской, если таковые и были, не оставили нам письменных свидетельств о себе и своём языке. Мы можем строить предположения, и они будут очень интересны. Но хотелось бы свести вопрос только к логике и 100% известным фактам о языке, в рамках тематики форума. Иначе, если затронуть доисторическое время, религию, эзотерику, объективного вывода не выйдет, а хотелось бы порассуждать не столь широко, но опираясь на сухие факты о развитии языка.

Comment: @Третий глаз Я вас поняла, я тоже стараюсь рассуждать в рамках. Если какой-то народ получает сложный язык из внешнего источника (пусть  это  "Бог дал язык человеку сразу во всей полноте"), то развитие языка будет сводиться к его упрощению. Язык будет приспосабливаться к окружающей жизни, к возможностям  и потребностям человека.  И это будет его прогрессивным развитием, так как многозначность слов и тяжеловесность грамматики станут препятствием для полноценного общения.

Comment: @Sharon а обратные примеры Вам не известны? Те, которые бы можно было бы противопоставить "изначально сложному языку"? Потому что упрощение мы действительно можем рассматривать как развитие. Но поверить в то,что язык появляется вот так сразу, с падежами и деепричастными оборотами, трудно. С простой человеческой позиции кажется куда более реалистичным обнаружить среди ранних памятников именно незамысловатую письменность. Неужели она в самом деле по всему миру зафиксированна именно на пике своей сложности? Версию о готовых языках из внешнего источника не опровергнуть фактами?

Comment: @Третий глаз Очень всё интересно, но, к сожалению, я не настолько знаю историю предмета. Можно предположить следующее: варвары завоевывают цивилизованный народ с его культурой и письменностью. Многое уничтожают, но некоторые письменные памятники сохраняются, а также определенное время происходит контакт с образованными людьми. Какие-то знания передаются, закрепляются на этом этапе. Может быть, как и  у нас,  происходит деление на книжную и разговорную речь. Но всё это только "может быть".

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо вам за вопрос, меня эта тема тоже интересует, хотя в специальные источники я не углублялась. Мне хотелось понять **ее при минимуме внешней информации – путем простого логического рассуждения.**  Ну и мнения знающих людей мне, конечно, интересны, но только в простом изложении и в обобщенном виде.

Я же сама думаю так: с развитием цивилизации язык тоже в конечном счете **развивается,** но путь этот не представляется **прямым и однозначным**. Дикари  в принципе не могут сразу создать что-либо сложное, но не надо забывать о внешних заимствованиях.

Вот наш язык. Я, к примеру, вполне довольна его развитием. Он уже  достаточно набрался силы, **внешние источники не смогут оказать на него заметного негативного влияния.** Даже притока новых слов и сленговых молодежных выражений не стоит опасаться – язык возьмет и из этого источника всё полезное, всю новизну, а ненужное отбросит. Опасность я вижу в ином – нашу грамматику могут упростить наши же лингвисты, обладающие такими возможностями, но это другая тема.

У нашего языка интересная история, так как на его развитие значительно повлиял **греческий язык, откуда пришла к нам книжная речь**  с  развитой грамматикой (это мнение Пушкина), до этого русский язык был разговорным. И вот в течение веков мы совершенствовали эту грамматику, и ее **улучшение шло в направлении упрощения**, такой вот парадокс.

Еще меня всегда интересовало сравнение **русского языка с английским.** Кажется, у англичан было нечто похожее в истории, когда чужой книжный язык сливался с местным разговорным. И вот их грамматика несколько другая: сложную систему времен они оставили, а падежи убрали. Вот я и пытаюсь понять, **кто из нас оказался в большем выигрыше.**

Comment: Кстати, на счёт сложной системы времён. Не знаю первоисточник этой информации. Сам я встречал её в пересказе Ю.Никитина. Он утверждал, что в русском языке времён даже больше, чем в английском, просто они не утверждены на уровне официальных справочников. Помню, в качестве примера он приводил следующие формы: махнул, махал, махивал, К нынешней теме это не при чём, но вдруг для сравнения языков будет интересно воспользоваться. Пример заметки на эту тему http://shipilov.com/mysli-i-zametki/140-vosem-vremen-russkogo-yazyka.html и ещё https://shkolazhizni.ru/school/articles/15886/

Comment: Спасибо, интересный материал. Мне эта информация вполне понятна и близка. Мы не избавились от времен в семантическом плане, а просто нашли другие грамматические формы для  их обозначения. И они мне кажутся более удобными, чем формализованная английская система глаголов.  Я считаю,что это было прогрессивным развитием.